# TypeError: this.mealService.getCardAssignment is not a function Angular 8

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am using two kendo-grid in one page. For some divine reason the 2nd grid is not working.
i am getting these errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txat7.png)

my first grid looks like this, which works fine

```
<kendo-grid [data]="allData"
              kendoGridSelectBy="id"
              [selectedKeys]="mySelection"
              [pageSize]="pageSize" [skip]="skip" [sort]="gridState.sort"
              [pageable]="true"
              [sortable]="true"
              [reorderable]="true"
              [resizable]="true"
              [scrollable]="true"
              [columnMenu]="{ filter: true }"
              (edit)="onEdit($event)"
              (remove)="onRemove($event)"
              (add)="onAdd($event)">
```

and the 2nd one looks like this

```
<kendo-grid [data]="cardAssignment"
                      [pageable]="true"
                      [sortable]="true"
                      [reorderable]="true"
                      [resizable]="true"
                      [scrollable]="true">
```

service to populate the 2nd grid looks like this:

```
this.mealService.getCardAssignment(bookedByData).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.guestsPerEmployee = resp;
      },
      (err: any) => {
        //ON ERROR
      },
      () => {
        //ON Success
        this.loadCardAssignmentGrid();
      }
    );
```

mealService:

```
getCardAssignment(params: any) {
    return this.api.post('v1/employees/GetCardAssignment', params);
  }
```

Comment: please include the code for the mealService

Comment: please check the question. I have edited this

Comment: How is the subscription triggered? Is it bound as callback?

Comment: yes. like a callback

Comment: You need to either bind the callback or an arrow function to use the `this` keyword. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/6513921

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the **`mealService`** in the constructor of  **`GateHouseAssignmentCardComponent`** like shown below:

```
constructor(private MealService:mealService){}
```

Comment: You are right, but this is not valid typescript code. It should be `private mealService: MealService)`.

Comment: @code-gorilla thanks for your feedback, corrected it.